# rails 4.0.0 processes css.scss paths but does not append hashes when precompiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, ruby-on-rails-4, precompile

In my land.css.scss I've got:

```
header { background: image-url( "logo.png" ) no-repeat scroll 0 0; }
```

When in dev mode that gets properly transformed to:

```
header { background: url(/assets/logo.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0; }
```

But when in production mode after rake assets:precompile logo.png gets copied to:

```
public/assets/logo-46ff46dc41a0f734725d64d2764ebbeb.png
```

But the **application.css** generated still has

`header { background: url(/assets/logo.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0; }` 
and does not add the hash at the end of the img path.

Any idea is greatly appreciated!

Note: Assets defined in the html.erb files are properly managed. image_tag "slide.png" is properly compiled into .png"/> :P

Answer (score 1):

Compile assets with following command:

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

See http://railsblog.kieser.net/2013/08/rails4-phusion-passenger-asset-pipeline.html

Comment: Ahhh so it's because of Passenger! Thanks for this.